Syntax Error with TRUNCATE/DELETE and CTE in Amazon Redshift using dbt
In my dbt project, I've encountered a syntax error when attempting to truncate or delete a table after defining a temporary table (temp_table) in the model.sql file. I am trying to execute this on AWS Redshift
-- dbt_project/models/initial_load/initial_load.sql

{{ config(
    materialized='table',
    table='overwrite'
) }}


-- Create a temporary table with records from table B plus filtered records from table A
WITH temp_table AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM {{ ref('table_b') }}
   UNION
   SELECT *
   FROM {{ source('my_source', 'table_a') }}
   WHERE -- Your filter condition here
)

-- Delete existing data from table A
TRUNCATE TABLE {{ ref('table_a') }}
--DELETE FROM TABLE {{ ref('table_a') }}

-- Insert data from temp_table into table A
INSERT INTO {{ ref('table_a') }}
SELECT *
FROM temp_table


A CTE (WITH clause) is a part of a SELECT statement, not a free standing statement.  "WITH temp_table AS ..." does not create a temp table but rather a virtual data reference that can be used elsewhere in the SELECT.
It looks like you want to save some data before the TRUNCATE and use it after the table has been cleared.  You will need to create an actual temp table (data on disk) to do this.  Something like
-- Create a temporary table with records from table B plus filtered records from table A
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM {{ ref('table_b') }}
   UNION
   SELECT *
   FROM {{ source('my_source', 'table_a') }}
   WHERE -- Your filter condition here
)

-- Delete existing data from table A
TRUNCATE TABLE {{ ref('table_a') }}
--DELETE FROM TABLE {{ ref('table_a') }}

-- Insert data from temp_table into table A
INSERT INTO {{ ref('table_a') }}
SELECT *
FROM temp_table


Getting below error after changing it to CREATE table                                               05:58:54  Database Error in model initial_load (model/core/initial_load.sql)
05:58:54    syntax error at or near "CREATE"
05:58:54    LINE 16: CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS

Can you post the actual SQL sent to the database?  A syntax error could be hidden in any of the replacement variables.  Or in basic syntax like finishing statements with ';'.
